# Cannot pass variable into CURL in .SH file. Works in Bash

Tags: bash, curl, cygwin

This code works directly in Bash.

```
$ var=/2013/08/21/politics/nsa-fisa-court/index.html
$ curl www.cnn.com/$var
```

However, if I put the exact code into a **.SH** file and call it from Bash I get:

> curl: (52) empty reply from server

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you created, `a.sh`, has windows line endings in it (CR-LF), which causes curl to ask for a URL with a CR at the end, which is treated as an error by the `nginx` server belonging to CNN.

Fix the line endings with `dos2unix` (or equivalent), and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix them with quotes. `a.sh` may look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

var="/2013/08/21/politics/nsa-fisa-court/index.html"
curl www.cnn.com/"$var"
```

change permission of the file.

```
chmod a+x a.sh
```

then execute `./a.sh`

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work. My code looks exactly like yours: `var="/2013/08/21/politics/nsa-fisa-court/index.html"
curl www.cnn.com/"$var"` except that I get: `me@me /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin
$ ./a.sh
curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: I don't think its permissions because if I run the same code with no variables it works fine

Comment: @iamauser: you don't need to quote strings with no whitespace or shell metacharacters in them. You're allowed to, but it makes absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Put `set -xv` at the beginning of the file, and `set +xv` at the end. The `set -xv` will turn on verbose and debugging.

Before each line in the shell script executes, it will show you what the line looks like before the variables, globs, patterns, etc. are interpolated, and what they look like afterwards.

It might not be the lines you expect.

Also, what editor are you using to build the shell script? If you're using Notepad on Windows to create the shell script and then posting it over to a Linux machine (or using cygwin), you will have the incorrect line endings. If you have the wrong line endings, you'll see all sorts of unexplained errors like that.

By the way, the quotes won't make any difference. Although a good idea, there's no problem with whitespace in your variable values.

Comment: Hmm I put in set -xv as suggested but received `me@me /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin
$ ./a.sh
: invalid optionset: -
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [arg ...]
./a.sh: line 2: $: command not found
./a.sh: line 3: $: command not found`

Comment: Yes, I did use notepad (which worked fine when no variables were involved). Perhaps that explains it.

Comment: @user2029890 - Never use Notepad. You should use a ___Programming editor___. Try [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org), You can set line endings, plus it has syntax coloring and auto-indenting. It's fre and works on Windows.